# [Android]Get string in Resource from Pageradapter

Tags: android

I want to get string source from **res/string** to use at Pageradapter.

As many posts said I made this code.

```
public class DonImageClass extends PagerAdapter{

..........
private static Activity myactivity;
public DonImageClass(Activity myactivity){
    this.myactivity  = myactivity;
}


String imageSource = myactivity.getResources().getString(R.string.changUrla);
...........
```

But it returns null exception because of this sentence;

```
String imageSource = myactivity.getResources().getString(R.string.changUrla);
```

How could I get the right answer?

I have been stuck on this issue more than a month.

It throw null point exception like this;

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung, PID: 4560
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException:

Comment: Why is `myactivity` `static`?

Comment: Please attach crashlog you're getting.

Comment: Actually I didn't understand it 100%... I just checked at internet. If you though that something was wrong, please tell me, bro.

Comment: @StasLelyuk wait I'll update

Comment: Crashlog you've added is not informative at the moment, please extend it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this my friend**

```
getResources().getString(R.string.yourstring)
```

**OR use**

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.yourstring)
```

Comment: Thank you my friend but I did it several times... Also didn't work.....

Comment: then you can dont user static methodgetApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.yourstring)

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE static field for Activity.

If you absolutely need that use SoftReference with Context instead of Activity, and get resources like this:

```
public class DonImageClass extends PagerAdapter{

..........
private SoftReference <Context> mContext;
public DonImageClass(Context context){
    this.mContext  = new SoftReference<Context>(context);
}

Context context = mContext.get();
if (context != null) {
    String imageSource = context.getResources().getString(R.string.changUrla);
}
...........
```

Could you describe what do you want to do? 
I will try than to offer you be solution.

Comment: I want to get resource from res/string and put it in URL(string) on pageradapter. I tried several method but most of them throw me null point exception... (I didn't check your answer yet, my bro.)

Comment: Hmm.... I can't get your SoftReference... What is it? Should I make another class as SoftReference? If than, what should I put it in??

Comment: import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

Answer (score 0):

```
String imageSource = myactivity.getResources().getString(R.string.changUrla);
```

Replace this with the given code below.

```
String imageSource = getResources().getString(R.string.changUrla);
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure... If I delete context or activity (at this time myactivity), I get red line from androidstudio. Is it possible to work properly??